# PHP statement synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: php, sql, asynchronous, synchronous

Good morning,
I would like to know if PHP prepare statement is synchronous or asynchronous, for example :

```
$req1 = "UPDATE ...";
$statement1 = $connection->prepare($req1);
$statement1->execute();

$req2 = "SELECT ...";
$statement2 = $connection->prepare($req2);
$statement2->execute();
```

So the result of the second request depend on the first, it may cause problems or wrong results, in others words, there's a possibility that the second request execute before the first.

I searched for answers, but i haven't found a clear answer.
Thanks you.

Comment: Relational databases have transactions that you can start/commit/rollback from within your PHP code; but code executes synchronously; the first statement execution will complete before the second is prepared and executed

Comment: use transactions, that would provide you data-integrity

Comment: Thanks, Now I should not worry about this !!

Answer (score 4):

Database queries are executed synchronously. But don't take my word for it, check the manual:

**PDO:** http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Since the method result is TRUE on success or FALSE on failure you can deduce it is synchronous.

**MySQLi:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Same here. So check the documentation and if the execute() returns something related to the result you know it has to be synchronous.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm sure that PDO run a prepared statement (SQL) request synchronously by default, in order to use asynchronous operations, you should use MySQLi.