# At what point does a web server start executing a request? Does it wait for the whole request content length or does it execute received chunks?

Tags: php, apache, https, server, request

I'm writing a PHP web app that will: (1) insert data into mysql database; (2) scale down and save user uploaded images in directory. If the second operation fails for any reason - be it network/system failure or someone accidentally kicked out the system cable, the inserted data in database will be a waste or invalid. That means none should fail.

So, how does the server handle request?

Comment: You can use DB transactions for this. During transaction, should anything fail,  all the DB related  inserts will not be processed. This is have it's done in Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions.

Comment: I think the following question and answer will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/45916794/11675758

Comment: I know about transaction. I forgot to add in my question that the data is generated on stage-by-stage basis. Perhaps, I'll be gathering all the data in an array as they are generated and use transaction. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB transactions for this. During transaction, should anything fail, all the DB related inserts will not be processed.

This is how it's done in Laravel - laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions.

This is an example of how it can be done outside of Laravel:

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    
    $db->query('Insert Query');
    $smallImage = $this->resizeImage($img);
    $this->saveImage($smallImage);
    
    $db->commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $db->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```